# How to mimic WP7 animation in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, animation

This is kind of weird. I'm building a page based off of WP7 and one of the main attractions to the OS is it's gorgeous animations. How would I go about creating the "tilt" or "flip" animation created when a live tile flips backwards.

I've searched everywhere and couldn't find what I was looking for. If you have any examples that would be great! Any help is always appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [jQuery](http://jquery.com) plugins like

http://www.webdeveloperjuice.com/2010/04/28/10-awesome-jquery-flip-plugins-for-next-level-interface/ for flip animations

or

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/tilt for accelerometer based tilts.

My personal fav is:

http://lab.smashup.it/flip/

Comment: Thanks so much! I'll definitely try these! I'll also make sure to show you the end result when it's finished!